# Compare multiple subsequent rows in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

Sample subscription data for customer A:

```
User_id Service subscription_start_date subscription_end_date
A   Prime   02/03/19    18/04/19
A   Prime   25/04/19    07/06/19
A   Prime   20/06/19    04/01/20
A   Prime   20/03/20    04/05/20
A   Prime   02/03/21    18/04/21
A   Prime   28/04/21    31/05/21
A   netflix 02/03/19    18/04/19
A   netflix 28/04/19    31/05/19
A   netflix 28/06/19    31/08/19
```

if next subscription_start_day is within 15 days of previous subscription end_date, then consider it to be subscription without GAP.

How can we bring below result:

```
User_id Service subscription_start_date subscription_end_date
A   Prime   02/03/19    04/01/20
A   Prime   20/03/20    04/05/20
A   Prime   02/03/21    31/05/21
A   netflix 02/03/19    31/05/19
A   netflix 28/06/19    31/08/19
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` to determine when a subscription begins (i.e. more than 15 days from the previous one).  Then use a cumulative sum to assign a subscription count and aggregate:

```
select user_id, service, min(subscription_start_date), max(subscription_end_date)
from (select s.*,
             sum(case when subscription_end_date > subscription_start_date - interval 15 day then 0 else 1
                 end) over (partition by partition by user_id, service
                            order by subscription_start_date
                           ) as grp
      from (select s.*,
                   lag(subscription_end_date) over (partition by user_id, service order by subscription_start_date) as prev_subscription_end_date
            from subscriptions s
           ) s
     ) s
group by user_id, service, grp;
```